# Why does `fontFamily` work on `TextView` but not on `Switch`?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use [XML fonts in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml). I have two views, one `TextView`:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Blaaah"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  app:fontFamily="@font/my_custom_font" />
```

And one `Switch`:

```
<Switch
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  android:text="Blaaah"
  app:fontFamily="@font/my_custom_font"/>
```

Put underneath each other, this is what they look like:

[image: TextView and Switch side by side]

The `TextView` picks up the font, the `Switch` does not. `Switch` inherits from `TextView`, so I'm at a bit of a loss why this doesn't work. If I do `switch.setTypeface(...)` from code, the font is picked up just fine. Does anybody have an idea what is going on, or how I might be able to set the `Switch`'s font from XML?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me,

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            style="@style/tvStyle_poppinsMedium_Small_Black"
            android:text="@string/push_notifications"                
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



  <style name="tvStyle_poppinsMedium_Small_Black">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_medium</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_small</item>
    </style>
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Hmm, `SwitchCompat` doesn't do it for me either, but I'm still using the old `android.support.v7` version. Maybe it's time to start that "move to AndroidX" project I've been putting off... If I manage to solve it with that I'll report back :).

Comment: Have you tried this with your switchCompat of android.support.v7? I think it will work with that also.

Comment: Yeah that was one of the things I tried, but it looks identical to the normal `Switch`. I'm using Xamarin and unfortunately the AndroidX packages still haven't surpassed RC stage, so I'm not quite ready to include those in this particular app. It's a bit surprising to me that this wouldn't work with the `v7` version, but on the other hand the `fontFamily` attribute is a relatively new feature..

Answer (score 0):

You can change switch component programmatically

```
switchObj.setSwitchTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "custom_font.ttf"));
```

Comment: I am aware of that, thanks - I'm wondering how to do it from XML. FWIW `setSwitchTypeface` sets the typeface of the switch button itself (the on / off text), I'm looking for the type face of the label (which indeed changes just fine using `setTypeface`.